# ta.valuewhen does not appear work consistently

Tags: time, pine-script

On a daily chart, I am trying to get the bar_index of the change in the month from two months back.

For example, today is 15th November, so I want the bar_index of the first daily candle in October.

The chart does not have a candle for the 1st October as that was a Sunday, so I want to get the bar_index for the 2nd October.

I would expect the following code to work, but it always returns the very last bar_index on the chart.

```
//This works
bgcolor(ta.change(time("M")) != 0 ? color.silver : na)

// This does not.
NewMonth = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(time("M")) != 0, bar_index, 1)
```

How can I accomplish what I seek?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the condition **Occurrence** value to 0

something like that:

```
NewMonth = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(time("M")) != 0, bar_index, 0)
```

Comment: Sadly, that does not work either, still gives a bar_index value far far in the future.